# Best Practices express.js

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I am working on a simple project to learn Express.js.

I need some clarifications on best practices for error handling.

What I have done so far:

Initially, I had try-catch blocks in each function in the controller(I do have some try-catch blocks still in the controller for asynchronous errors), but now I have added a global error handler middleware.

In my app.js
after all my routes, I have the errorLogger middleware. In this, I am logging an error to a file and then sending the response. If it is an operational error I am sending the respective response else 500.

Before the errorLogger but after my routes, I am checking for undefined routes and setting the response to 404 and appropriate message.

Clarification needed:

- Is this the generally followed approach?
- I saw that it is good to handle unhandledRejection and uncaughtException and terminate the process gracefully. (sample code snippets would be helpful)
- Also, should I log the errors in a separate log file?
- When any request is made I am first logging it in an eventLog file. I wanted to know if I should log errors separate. And where would operational error logs be in?

Would be great if I can get some advice on how to go about these.

Thank You